# MySQL table - performance, count of indexes

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I have table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `supplies` (
 `cycle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `market_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `offered_order` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`,`market_id`,`cycle_id`,`price`),
 KEY `fk_supplies_subjects` (`subject_id`),
 KEY `fk_supplies_markets` (`market_id`),
 KEY `fk_supplies_currencies` (`currency_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_currencies` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `currencies` (`currency_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_subjects` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subjects` (`subject_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_markets` FOREIGN KEY (`market_id`) REFERENCES `markets` (`market_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Table has about 20,000 rows. I have problems with performance. I am logging SQL queries that are taking long time and from the log I can see:

1. Slow `INSERT`s into table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO supplies VALUES (11, 'userName', 18, 30, 'pound', 20) ;
   ```
2. Slow `DELETE`s from table

   ```
   DELETE FROM supplies WHERE cycle_id = 6 AND market_id = 18 AND subject_id =  'userName' ;
   ```

**What could I improve?**

I guess, changing the indexes would help, because the `PRIMARY` key is formed from 4 columns (and some are even `varchars`). But how should I change the indexes?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why did you choose to have non-integer ids?

Comment: @Strawberry - I did not design this table, my goal is to optimize it. I will change the ids to integer.

Comment: It does not seem 'right' to include `price` in the `PRIMARY KEY`; please explain.

Comment: @RickJames see more about it in https://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-great-primary-key-debate/

Comment: @AndréLima - If your point is that adding price leads to uniqueness, then OK.  But 123 dollars is not the same as 123 Euros, so shouldn't currency_id be added?

Comment: Most of the indexes are because of `FOREIGN KEYs` -- This points out the cost of FKs, not of indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a primary key with only one field. This is a basic performance optimization

```
CREATE TABLE `supplies` (
 `supplies_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cycle_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subject_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `market_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `currency_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `offered_order` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`supplies_id`),
 INDEX `index` (`subject_id` ASC,`market_id` ASC,`cycle_id` ASC,`price` ASC))
 KEY `fk_supplies_subjects` (`subject_id`),
 KEY `fk_supplies_markets` (`market_id`),
 KEY `fk_supplies_currencies` (`currency_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_currencies` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `currencies` (`currency_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_subjects` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subjects` (`subject_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_supplies_markets` FOREIGN KEY (`market_id`) REFERENCES `markets` (`market_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Another possible improvement can be removing cascade constraints. Check if they are really necessary.

Comment: Well, I believe this will speed up the INSERTS, but what about the DELETES?

Comment: A primary key with only one field will speed up both inserts and deletes. Removing cascade constraints will speed up deletes and updates.

Comment: Please explain the rationale behind "one field PK is better".

Comment: @AndréLima - The number of columns in the PK does not impact ins/del performance; the number of secondary keys does -- but not enough to worry about.

Comment: Since there are 4 secondary keys, the addition of a surrogate key actually decreases the overall space needed (versus the original 4-column PK).  It _probably_ slows down `SELECTs`, `INSERTs`, and `DELETEs`.  But without further info on the queries, it is hard to say by how much.